# Cannot cast child to the parent class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, .net-core

I have a class definition like:

```
 public abstract class Index<TKey> : IComparer<Computer>, IEnumerable<TKey>
        where TKey:IComparable
```

then another class implements this as:

```
public class ScreenSizeIndex : Index<double>
```

then i would like to consume this like

```
Index<IComparable> index = new ScreenSizeIndex();
```

then the compiler complains with:

> CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IComparable' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

double shold be assignable to IComparable, So the implementation of Index shoudl be assignable to Index, then why the compiler complans about thie assigmnet

Comment: It tries to convert IComparable to double not the other way round.

Comment: `Index<IComparable>` is not the same as `Index<double>`, even though `double` can be assigned to `IComparable`. research covariance in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this might not seem very intuitive, but is really simple. Generic Types with different generic parameters are (mostly) considered completely different types in C#, no matter whether one of the type parameters can be assigned to the other or not. You can try doing this with any generic type, like assigning a `List<double>` to a `List<IComparable>` or a `List<object>`, it will never work, as long as the type parameters of what you are assigning to and what you are assigning are not exactly the same.

The following code would work perfectly fine because `ScreenSizeIndex` is an `Index<double>` by definition.

```
Index<double> index = new ScreenSizeIndex();
```

---

EDIT:

I thought I should maybe give some more insight on this topic.

### Why it doesn't work (invariance)

Imagine the following generic class:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public T GetBar() {
        // return some value of type T
    }
    public void SetBar(T value) {
        // do something with the value of type T
    }

}
```

Now, if you have, say, a `Foo<string>`, you can be absolutely sure that `GetBar()` will always return a `string`. And now you might be thinking, well, because a `string` is also always an `IComparable`, a `Foo<string>` could easily be treated like a `Foo<IComparable>` because the returned value will still have the correct type, so this

```
Foo<IComparable> foo = new Foo<string>();
IComparable bar = foo.GetBar();
```

should be possible.

And yes, if we're only talking about `T` being the return type of a method, that train of thought would be correct. But what if we call `SetBar()` where the function parameter is of type `T`? Well, if you could have a `Foo<string>` stored as a `Foo<IComparable>`, the variable of type `Foo<IComparable>` would allow you to pass any `IComparable` into `SetBar()` like this:

```
Foo<IComparable> foo = new Foo<string>();
foo.SetBar(4.2f);
```

The compiler would allow this because `float` implements `IComparable` and that's all that a `Foo<IComparable>` can expect, however, the method call will fail at runtime when trying to pass a `float` to the `SetBar(string)` method of the `Foo<string>` object that is actually stored.

Therefore, the compiler just doesn't allow these situations from happening at all.

---

### Covariance and Contravariance

This specific behavior is called **invariance** and applies to most generic types. The only possible exceptions to that are generic **interfaces** and **delegates**, which, if specified by the corresponding interface or delegate, can behave exactly the way you were trying to achieve.

The behavior that we have been talking about this entire time is called **covariance**. When defining a generic interface, putting the keyword `out` in front of a generic type parameter will make it covariant. You can see this in the declaration of the interface `IEnumerable<out T>`, for example. And if we test this out, we can see it actually works just fine:

```
IEnumerable<IComparable> a = new List<string>();
```

This, however, has two conditions:

1. The generic type parameter defined with the `out` keyword can only be used as a method return type or the type of read-only properties, read-only fields or static fields (and if I understood that correctly, future versions will also allow a covariant type parameter to be used as the type of parameters of static methods).
2. Covariance only works with reference types. Value types never support covariance (which is why I used `string` as an example type rather than `double`). Trying to assign an `IEnumerable<double>` to an `IEnumerable<IComparable>` will not be allowed by the compiler.

Also, note that covariance only works one way, so you can assign an `IEnumerable<string>` to an `IEnumerable<IComparable>`, but not the other way around. That would be **contravariance**.

Contravariance is just the exact opposite of covariance. It means that you can assign an instance of a generic type to a variable where the type arguments are more derived. Just like covariant type parameters, contravariant type parameters are declared using a keyword, in this case `in`. An example of this is the `Action<in T> delegate`.

```
Action<object> x = Console.WriteLine;
Action<string> y = x;
```

Again, there are two conditions for contravariant type parameters:

1. The generic type parameter defined with the `in` keyword can only be used as the type of method parameters, write-only properties or static fields (and again, if I understood it correctly, future versions will also allow a contravariant type parameter to be used as the return type of static methods). Also, note that when using a contravariant type parameter for a method parameter, that method parameter must be by-value and therefore cannot use the `in`, `out` or `ref` keywords (and yes, the `in` and `out` keywords for method parameters mean something completely different from type parameters).
2. Like covariance, contravariance only works with reference types, so you cannot assign an `Action<IComparable>` to an `Action<double>`.

And again, contravariance only works one way, so assigning an `Action<string>` to an `Action<object>` will not work either.

Contravariance often confuses people, but it makes sense if you think about it. Looking at the example above:

```
Action<object> x = Console.WriteLine;
Action<string> y = x;
```

This works with no issues because the underlying `Action<object>` still accepts any `object`. So calling `y("Test")` will work fine, because all `string`s are `object`s. However, the other way around, we would get into trouble, just like I described with the `Foo<T>` interface above.

---

I hope this edit is helpful to anyone looking for a behavior similar to the one described in the original question.